# Represent a "list of lists" in a ReportViewer

Tags: c#, rdlc, reportviewer

I want to represent a list of lists in one of my ReportViewers.

An example of my situation would be the following:
In my code I have a list of elements of a specific class.
For example:

```
ObservableCollection<GroupClass> listOfItems = new ObservableCollection<GroupClass>();
```

I would have no problem to represent this list in my report if all the properties of my class were simple properties (string, int, ...). But my problem is that within this class I also have a list:

```
public class GroupClass
{
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<ItemPattern> ItemsGroup { get; set; }
}

public class ItemPattern
{
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public string ItemValue { get; set; }
}
```

To show this information in my WPF window I have no problem, but I have no idea how I can do to represent a list of lists simply in a ReportViewer.
Currently, listOfItems can have up to 20 elements. While ItemsGroup can also reach up to 20 items.

The only way I can think of is to create 20 tables in the report and create 20 DataSets to bind them to each of my elements in the following way:

```
this.GroupBindingSource.DataSource = listOfItems[0].ItemsGroup;
if (listOfItems.Count > 1)
{
    this.GroupBindingSource2.DataSource = listOfItems[1].ItemsGroup;
    if (listOfItems.Count > 2)
    {
        this.GroupBindingSource3.DataSource = listOfItems[2].ItemsGroup;
        ...

        if (listOfItems.Count > 19)
            this.GroupBindingSource20.DataSource = listOfItems[19].ItemsGroup;
    }
}
```

[image: report example]

Can someone guide me to make it easier and maintainable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve that using a SubReport. I followed the next guide:
https://marcelwouters.wordpress.com/2011/06/01/showing-a-report-with-a-subreport-in-the-reportviewer-control-which-has-a-odata-service-as-datasource-in-a-wpf-application/